# XSL adding up values

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have a XMl file where I need to extract out some information and sum up values. 
In the XSL file I'm unsure if I need the for-each loop. 
I think the XSL will explain what I'm trying to do.

Here's the XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="uppgift3.xsl"?>    
<autoads>
    <ad>
        <type>1</type>
        <name>Honda</name>
        <model>XL 1000 V</model>
        <regyear>2001</regyear>
        <price>129900</price>
        <adtext>2001 Honda XL 1000 V, 8.900 km. h?g vindruta. Pris 129.900kr,-.  </adtext>
        <addate>20020115</addate>
        <volume>1000</volume>
        <category></category>
    </ad>
    <ad>
        <type>2</type>
        <name>Nissan</name>
        <model>Almera 1.4S</model>
        <regyear>1997</regyear>
        <price>119000</price>
        <adtext>1997 Nissan Almera 1.4S, 5 d?rrar, met, 70.000 km. el.spegel/f?nster, galv. kaross, c.l?s, startsp?rr, airbag, nedf?llb. baks. ABS, ute temp. R/CD, alarm, d.fte, v.s?ten, s/v-hj.  EU-godk. full service, servo. Pris 119.000 kr,-.  </adtext>
        <addate>20020118</addate>
        <volume>0</volume>
        <category>5 d?rrrar</category>
    </ad>
    <ad>
        <type>2</type>
        <name>Mercedes-Benz</name>
        <model>C220 Elegance</model>
        <regyear>1995</regyear>
        <price>209000</price>
        <adtext>1995 Mercedes-Benz C220 Elegance, 4 d?rrar, 88.000 km. skinn, klima/automatic, cruise, el.spegel/f?nster, alu.f?lgar, c.l?s, airbag, antispinn,  ABS, ute temp, radio, s/v-hjul, servo, creme skinn. automat. Pris 209.000 kr,-.  </adtext>
        <addate>20020118</addate>
        <volume>0</volume>
        <category>4 d?rrar</category>
    </ad>
    <ad>
        <type>2</type>
        <name>Audi</name>
        <model>S8</model>
        <regyear>2000</regyear>
        <price>850000</price>
        <adtext>2000 Audi S8, 4 d?rrar, 40.000 km. 4x4, Tiptronic-aut., klimataut., ABS, el.f?nster/speglar/s?ten, soltak, c.l?s, servo, airbag, startsp?rr, antispinn, cruise., alu., trnred., sort skinn, mitttarmst?d., sportss?ten, stereo, alarm, s/v-hjul, dragkrok, 17"+18"alu. Pris 850.000 kr,-.  </adtext>
        <addate>20020118</addate>
        <volume>0</volume>
        <category>4 d?rrar</category>
    </ad>
    <ad>
        <type>1</type>
        <name>Yamaha</name>
        <model>Thunderace 1000</model>
        <regyear>2000</regyear>
        <price>130000</price>
        <adtext>2000 Yamaha Thunderace 1000, 11.500 km. R?d/Silver,tankv?ska medf?ljer. 146hk Pris kan diskuteras vid snabb affär Pris 130.000 kr,-.  </adtext>
        <addate>20020116</addate>
        <volume>1000</volume>
        <category></category>
    </ad>
    <ad>
        <type>2</type>
        <name>Audi</name>
        <model>A4 1.6</model>
        <regyear>2000</regyear>
        <price>260000</price>
        <adtext>2000 Audi A4 1.6, 4 d?rrar, 78.000 km. el.f?nster, ABS, alu. airbag, , klima, ESP, navig. plus, TV, evt. inbyte, power box (+30 HK) medf?ljer. Pris 260.000 kr,-.  </adtext>
        <addate>20020117</addate>
        <volume>0</volume>
        <category>4 d?rrar</category>
    </ad>
    <ad>
        <type>2</type>
        <name>Jeep</name>
        <model>Grand Cherokee 2.5TD</model>
        <regyear>0</regyear>
        <price>359000</price>
        <adtext>0 Jeep Grand Cherokee 2.5TD, Stv., 38.000 km. A/C, el.f?mster/spegel, 8xalu., c.l?s, airbag, R/CD, s/v-hjul, servo. Pris 359.000 kr,-.  </adtext>
    </ad>
    <ad>
        <type>1</type>
        <name>Suzuki</name>
        <model>TL 1000 R</model>
        <regyear>1998</regyear>
        <price>110000</price>
        <adtext>1998 Suzuki TL 1000 R, 8400 km. Pris 110.000 kr,-.  </adtext>
        <addate>20020116</addate>
        <volume>1000</volume>
        <category></category>
    </ad>
    <ad>
        <type>2</type>
        <name>Volkswagen</name>
        <model>Golf 1.8 Pink Floyd</model>
        <regyear>1994</regyear>
        <price>85000</price>
        <adtext>1994 Volkswagen Golf 1.8 Pink Floyd, 4 d?rrar, 135.600 km. Eu-godk?nd, airbag, el.taklucka, just ratt, metallic, radio/CD/Kass, s/v-hjul, servicebok, servo, stereo. Fullst?ndig service, 1 ?gare, 6 h?gtalare. Pris 85.000 kr,-.  </adtext>
        <addate>20020115</addate>
        <volume>0</volume>
        <category>4 d?rrar</category>
    </ad>
    <ad>
        <type>2</type>
        <name>Volvo</name>
        <model>850 2.0 LT</model>
        <regyear>1997</regyear>
        <price>245490</price>
        <adtext>1997 Volvo 850 2.0 LT, Stv., 122785 km. halvskinn, el.spegel/f?nster/soltak, fj.c.l?s, st.sp?rr, airbag, just.ratt, rails, nedf.baks闁剁€岆 m.armst?d, ABS, rad/kass, alarm, dragkrok, s/v-hjul, f.glass, met, garanti, servo. Pris 245.490 kr,-.  </adtext>
    </ad>
    <ad>
        <type>2</type>
        <name>Audi</name>
        <model>A3 1.6 Ambition</model>
        <regyear>1998</regyear>
        <price>180000</price>
        <adtext>1998 Audi A3 1.6 Ambition, 3 d?rrar, 88.000 km. s/v-hj. el.f?nster, ABS, f.glass, alu. c.l?s, servo, airbag, rostfri, stilig bil. Pris 180.000 kr,-.  </adtext>
        <addate>20020117</addate>
        <volume>0</volume>
        <category>3 d?rrar</category>
    </ad>
    <ad>
        <type>1</type>
        <name>BMW</name>
        <model>K 1200 RS</model>
        <regyear>2000</regyear>
        <price>195000</price>
        <adtext>2000 BMW K 1200 RS, 4.000 km. sidov?skor, bagageften. Pris 195.000 kr,-.  </adtext>
        <addate>20020116</addate>
        <volume>1200</volume>
        <category></category>
    </ad>
    <ad>
        <type>2</type>
        <name>Suzuki</name>
        <model>Baleno 1.6 GLX</model>
        <regyear>1999</regyear>
        <price>175000</price>
        <adtext>1999 Suzuki Baleno 1.6 GLX, Stv., 49.500 km. A/C, el.f?nster/speil, c.l?s, airbag, rails, ABS, stereo, , servo. Pris 175.000 kr,-.  </adtext>
    </ad>
    <ad>
        <type>1</type>
        <name>Suzuki</name>
        <model>LS 650 Savage</model>
        <regyear>1987</regyear>
        <price>29000</price>
        <adtext>1987 Suzuki LS 650 Savage, r?d. Pris 29.000 kr,-.  </adtext>
        <addate>20020116</addate>
        <volume>650</volume>
        <category></category>
    </ad>
    <ad>
        <type>1</type>
        <name>Suzuki</name>
        <model>GS 500 E</model>
        <regyear>1993</regyear>
        <price>31900</price>
        <adtext>1993 Suzuki GS 500 E. Pris 31.900,-.  </adtext>
        <addate>20020117</addate>
        <volume>500</volume>
        <category></category>
    </ad>
    <ad>
        <type>2</type>
        <name>BMW</name>
        <model>520 i</model>
        <regyear>2000</regyear>
        <price>387000</price>
        <adtext>2000 BMW 520 i, Stv., 52.600 km. Skinn, klima, m.f.ratt, el.spegel/f?nster, alu.f?lgar, c.l?s, airbag x 6, antispinn, rails, trnt, ABS, rad/cd, alarm, dragkrok, met, servo, Pris 387.000 kr,-.  </adtext>
    </ad>
    <ad>
        <type>1</type>
        <name>Triumph</name>
        <model>Daytona T 595</model>
        <regyear>1997</regyear>
        <price>115000</price>
        <adtext>1997 Triumph Daytona T 595, 13.000 km. som ny, karbon anl?gg, nya d?ck, extra tank. Pris 115.000 kr,-.  </adtext>
        <addate>20020115</addate>
        <volume>955</volume>
        <category></category>
    </ad>
    <ad>
        <type>2</type>
        <name>Mitsubishi</name>
        <model>Pajero 2.5 TD</model>
        <regyear>1987</regyear>
        <price>59000</price>
        <adtext>1987 Mitsubishi Pajero 2.5 TD, Stv. 4x4, dragkrok, servo, mycket utr., ingen rost. Pris 59.000 kr,-.  </adtext>
    </ad>
</autoads>
```

Here's my XSL file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"> 
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <body>
                <h2>Fordon till salu</h2>
                <div>
                    <xsl:for-each select="autoads/ad">
                    <xsl:sort select="regyear" order="ascending" />
                        <div style="margin:15px;"> 
                            <xsl:choose>
                                <xsl:when test="regyear &lt; 1999">
                                    <span style="margin-right:10px;font-weight:bold;float:left;">Total amount of cars before 1999: </span>
                                    <div><xsl:value-of select="sum(//name)" /></div>

                                    <span style="margin-right:5px;font-weight:bold;float:left;">Total amount of cars with automatic gear: </span>
                                    <div><xsl:value-of select="model" /></div> 

                                    <span style="margin-right:5px;font-weight:bold;float:left;">Average price for cars before 1999: </span>
                                    <div><xsl:value-of select="sum(//price[regyear &lt; 1999])" /></div>
                                </xsl:when>
                                <xsl:otherwise>
                                    <span style="margin-right:10px;font-weight:bold;float:left;">Total amount of cars from 1999 and onwards: </span>
                                    <div><xsl:value-of select="name" /></div>

                                    <span style="margin-right:5px;font-weight:bold;float:left;">Total amount of cars with automatic gear: </span>
                                    <div><xsl:value-of select="model" /></div> 

                                    <span style="margin-right:5px;font-weight:bold;float:left;">Average price for cars from 1999 and onwards: </span>
                                    <div><xsl:value-of select="regyear" /></div>
                                </xsl:otherwise>
                            </xsl:choose>
                        </div>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </div>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I've edited my answer to show expected result. Thank for the input guys.
So having the XML file and XSL file I want the result to be:

```
Total amount of cars before 1999: 
Total amount of cars with automatic gear: 
Average price for cars before 1999: 

Total amount of cars from 1999 and onwards: 
Total amount of cars with automatic gear: 
Average price for cars from 1999 and onwards:
```

The result of the above is not calculated yet. Tnx again!

I'm trying to extract information from the adtext that is provided in the XML file.
That is I'm trying to extract the amount of cars that have the work "automat" in the adtext.
The result should be 1 for < 1999 and 1 for >= 1999.

```
<h2 style="margin:0">Antal bilar med automat v&#228;xell&#229;da: <xsl:value-of select="count(/autoads/ad[regyear &lt; 1999][type = 2]/adtext[contains(., 'automat')])" /></h2>
```

Comment: Can you be more precise as to what you are trying to sum (or count)? It would help if you showed your expected output, and the output you currently get (or if you get an error, which I suspect might be happening...). Thanks!

Comment: "I think the XSL will explain" You shouldn't use such assumptions on StackOverflow. We value quality questions and answers, so try to be as clear as possible without relying on your code to explain it all. 
That being said, as @Tim explained, when dealing with XSLT (or regular expressions for that matter), we expect an input, an XSL, the output you get (or the error) and the desired output.

Comment: Edit my question above. Thnx for the input guys!

Comment: And don't forget to put the actual totals you expect in your expected output too. Thanks.

Comment: You've tagged your question with _both_ xslt-1.0 and xslt-2.0 - given your example is 1.0 I presume this is the version you actually want, but please confirm and remove whichever is the inappropriate tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you are actually getting an error, because of this line

```
 <xsl:value-of select="sum(//name)" />
```

`name` contains a string, not a number, add you can't add up words!

If you only want total values, such as a sum, or a count, you don't need the `xsl:for-each` otherwise you will get the totals for each car in your XML.

To get the total cars before 1999, for example, you just need to use the `count` function, outside of any loop

```
 <xsl:value-of select="count(ad[regyear &lt; 1999])" />
```

(This assumes you are currently positioned on the `autoads` element, by the way.)

To get the number of cars before 1999 with automatic gears, you would do this (assuming that `type` of 2 is automatic....)

```
<xsl:value-of select="count(ad[regyear &lt; 1999][type = 2])" />
```

And to get the average price, you would do this....

```
<xsl:value-of select="sum(ad[regyear &lt; 1999]/price) div count(ad[regyear &lt; 1999])" />
```

Of course, if you wanted to do the same for cars from 1999 onwards, it would be similar, but you would end up with a lot of code repetition. So you could use a named template to do the totals, and pass in the cars you wish to count as a parameter.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"> 
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:template match="/autoads">
        <html>
            <body>
                <h2>Fordon till salu</h2>
                <xsl:call-template name="totals">
                    <xsl:with-param name="ads" select="ad[regyear &lt; 1999]" />
                </xsl:call-template>
                <xsl:call-template name="totals">
                    <xsl:with-param name="ads" select="ad[regyear >= 1999]" />
                </xsl:call-template>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="totals">
        <xsl:param name="ads" />

        <div style="margin:15px;"> 
            <span style="margin-right:10px;font-weight:bold;float:left;">Total amount of cars before 1999: </span>
            <div><xsl:value-of select="count($ads)" /></div>

            <span style="margin-right:5px;font-weight:bold;float:left;">Total amount of cars with automatic gear: </span>
            <div><xsl:value-of select="count($ads[type = 2])" /></div>

            <span style="margin-right:5px;font-weight:bold;float:left;">Average price for cars before 1999: </span>
            <div><xsl:value-of select="sum($ads/price) div count($ads)" /></div>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Big thank you Tim C. I'm gonna try your suggestion and then accept it as an answer!

Comment: Added one more question above :)

Comment: You really should be asking a whole new question, rather than amending your original question after it has been asked and answered. Thanks!